# Count Skip Records When Zero

Tags: postgresql

I want to have the monthly count (from current month) of visits from each location on the database. I have 3 locations and the supposed/ desired result should be:

```
visit_count |   location_name
------------------------------
    1       |    location1
    0       |    location2
    0       |    location3
```

This is the query I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(visits.visit_date) as visit_count, locations.location_name FROM locations 
LEFT JOIN VISITS ON locations.location_name = visits.location_checkin
WHERE locations.group_id = 1 AND date_trunc('month', current_date) <= visits.visit_date AND visits.visit_date < date_trunc('month', current_date) + INTERVAL '1 month' 
GROUP BY locations.location_name
```

But I'm just getting:

```
visit_count |   location_name
------------------------------
    1       |    location1
```

It's dismissing the locations I suppose because there's no data on them, but what I need is to show them to me even if they don't have any visits.

Does anyone knows what I'm missing?

Comment: Move your filter conditions that reference table `visits` into the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN` clause, otherwise they filter out those 0 count rows...

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but by putting the location checkin counts in a sub query anything missing can be picked up with left join after. Coalesce will fill in zero instead of null in the result.

```
SELECT Coalesce(v.visit_count,0) visit_count, locations.location_name
    FROM locations
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT location_checkin, count(visit_date) visit_count FROM visits
                   WHERE date_trunc('month', current_date) <= visit_date AND visit_date < date_trunc('month', current_date) + INTERVAL '1 month'
                   GROUP BY locations) v 
        ON v.location_checkin = locations.location_name
    WHERE locations.group_id = 1;
```